# Postgresql At least 2 sales in the same day

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry about my english
I have to get all the records what has the same date at least 2 times , i mean i want to know whos seller make at least 2 sales in the same date.

**Table A**

```
id          Name    Lastname     Seller     Date     Item
23456     Roberto Rodriguez    jvazquez 01/01/2013   auto
23423     Roberto Rodriguez    jvazquez 01/01/2013   moto
5654      Julián Domínguez     rfleita  05/02/2013   lancha
34534653  Romina Santaolaya    jvazquez 02/02/2013   moto
346534    Romina Santaolaya    rfleita  05/02/2013   auto
```

**Result**

```
23456     Roberto Rodriguez    jvazquez 01/01/2013   auto
23423     Roberto Rodriguez    jvazquez 01/01/2013   moto
346534    Romina Santaolaya    rfleita  05/02/2013   auto
5654      Julián Domínguez     rfleita  05/02/2013   lancha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, 
       Name,
       Lastname,
       Seller,
       Date,
       Item
from (
  select id, 
         Name,
         Lastname,
         Seller,
         Date,
         Item,
         count(*) over (partition by date, seller) as cnt
   from the_table
) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7c0cc/4

If you don't need the additional columns, Joel's answer will be quicker.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT seller, Date, COUNT(*) "Sales"
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Date, seller
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, but i need only who makes at least 2 sales in the same day.I mean if i sale 4 sales in a period of time 2 sales in 2013-06-01 1 sale in 2013-06-23 and 1 sale 2013-06-25. I want to get only the data of de sales of 2013-06-01 because i sale 2 sale in the same day.

Comment: This should give you that. Did you try the query?

Comment: Ah: I see your issue. I was thinking the ID was the seller ID.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result asked for:

```
SELECT *
    FROM TableA
    WHERE (Date, Seller) IN (
        SELECT Date, Seller
            FROM TableA
            GROUP BY Date, Seller
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
    )
```

Comment: Right. Not thinking through :)